# Links not working in jQuery clickable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have clickable columns that move, yet I need the links within them to work.  Unfortunately, I am not proficient in jQuery.  The issue must be with the triggers (?), but I don't see the work around.  I also apologize if this has been answered, for I do not know if I've used the correct terminology when searching.

Here is where my (half) working code can be found:
http://jsfiddle.net/28XNH/5/

Script:

```
$(".image-container").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
        });
        $(".posts").trigger("click");

$(".head").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
        });
        $(".posts").trigger("click");

$(".inner-container").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
        });
        $(".posts").trigger("click");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="profilemore">

<div id="page-wrap">

<div class="infoCol">
<a class="tigers head" href=""><span style="font-size:12pt;  font-weight:bold;">Tigers</span></a>
<div class="image-container" style="height:100%;">
<div  class="inner-container" style="height:100%;">
<div>
Here is a little about tigers.  For more information, please visit <a href="http://worldwildlife.org/species/tiger">The WWF</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="infoCol">
<a class="giantpandas head" href=""><span style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold;">Giant Pandas</span></a>
<div class="image-container" style="height:100%;">
<div class="inner-container" style="height:100%;">
<div>
Here is a little about giant pandas.  For more information, please visit <a href="http://worldwildlife.org/species/giant-panda">The WWF</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="infoCol">
<a class="polarbears head" href=""><span style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold;">Polar Bears</span></a>
<div class="image-container" style="height:100%;">
<div class="inner-container" style="height:100%;">
<div>
Here is a little about polar bears.  For more information, please visit <a href="http://worldwildlife.org/species/polar-bear">The WWF</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can this code be salvaged?  What am I missing?

Comment: e.preventDefault is exactly as it says, it prevents your default actions, i.e clicking links and then being redirected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your scripts to this:

```
$(".image-container").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
});

$(".posts").trigger("click");

$(".head").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
});

$(".posts").trigger("click");

$(".inner-container").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
});

$(".posts").trigger("click");
```

I'm no expert, but I believe the `e.preventDefault()` calls are stopping your links from responding to the click events.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/28XNH/7/)

**Edit:**

To get your links to open in a new tab, add the `target` attribute to their tags.

They'll look something like this:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">This is your link.</a>
```

**Edit 2:**

On another note, your HTML is not syntactically correct. Here's the same HTML, tidied up:

```
<div id="profilemore">
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div class="infoCol">
            <a class="tigers head" href=""><span style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold;">Tigers</span></a>

            <div class="image-container" style="height:100%;"></div>
            <div class="inner-container" style="height:100%;">Here is a little about tigers. For more information, please visit <a href="http://worldwildlife.org/species/tiger">The WWF</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCol">
        <a class="giantpandas head" href=""><span style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold;">Giant Pandas</span></a>

        <div class="image-container" style="height:100%;">
            <div class="inner-container" style="height:100%;">Here is a little about giant pandas. For more information, please visit <a href="http://worldwildlife.org/species/giant-panda">The WWF</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCol">
        <a class="polarbears head" href=""><span style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold;">Polar Bears</span></a>

        <div class="image-container" style="height:100%;">
            <div class="inner-container" style="height:100%;">Here is a little about polar bears. For more information, please visit <a href="http://worldwildlife.org/species/polar-bear">The WWF</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: correct answer - might also want to change the target to "_blank" so you open a new tab, maybe that's the goal as well, since you have an animation on click.

Comment: Thank you! That makes the links work, but there seems to be an issue with the headers now.  When clicked, they won't expand.

Comment: @Alex0521 Add those details to the original post and I'll do what I can to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Alex0521 Otherwise, mark this answer as correct and open another question for your other issue.

Comment: Yes, I seem to be getting an error: {"error": "Please use POST request"}  This is my first post, I wasn't sure what to do.  I'll open a new question.

Comment: @Alex0521 I did see that as well. Revisit my fiddle and use the code that's in there.

Comment: Ah, there was an easy fix.  I didn't add a #.  So, it should read <a class="tigers head" href="#">, <a class="giantpandas head" href="#">, <a class="polarbears head" href="#">

Comment: That does work, however if you want to avoid the `#` being added to the current URL, you can replace it with `javascript:void(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

The call to preventDefault in the handler for .image-container is stopping the links from working. Fortunately, it doesn't seem necessary.

Also, you shouldn't need separate handlers for .image-container and .inner-container because they do the same thing and .inner-container clicks will bubble up to their image-container.

Lastly, you probably want to stopPropagation on links in the image-container so that the JS doesn't do anything before they redirect.

```
$(".image-container").click(function(e){
    $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
});

$(".head").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent(".infoCol").addClass("currentCol").siblings().removeClass("currentCol");
 });

$('.image-container').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagaion();
}

$(".posts").trigger("click");
```